# What does the print() here do?

Tags: python

This is taken from a code:

```
print()
for letter in message:
if letter.lower() not in VOWELS:
new_message += letter
```

I have seen this several times without explanation. What does the print() actually contribute with here?

Comment: Have you tried removing it to see what the difference is? The default `end` is `'\n'`, so `print()` will just produce a new line.

Comment: I suggest reading the documentation for that method. Also, ask the maintainer of that code what is does.

Comment: it prints whatever is in between the two brackets on to the screen, followed by a new line.

Comment: I have tried it in one scenario and it makes no visible difference :/

Comment: It will only print an empty line(`\n`) here.

Comment: @ergonaut and KevinGuan thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That will only print an extra line '\n'. It will for sure do nothing if it was like:

```
print(end='')
```

print() has a parameter called 'end' is set to '\n' by default 
so when you say end='' that means you just overwritten 'end' with an empty string